# sed in one folder

Tags: sed, requirements

i need 'sed' for some batch;

now there are a lot of requirements;

could anyone tell me how to put all the requirements and sed itself to run in one dir?? [so no need for install, that it works]

'Cause i need to get the batch file public, all that requirements seem to give a lot of work for the users...

Comment: i think you should ask your question properly. give example of input and output files where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind;;

i used something other to get what i wanted.

EDIT: For those who want to know how to do this without installing sed, just use a bat to exe converter to put them together into one EXE file. Or just make sure you put sed into the running directory of the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about distributing the sed binary?

If so, then you could run ldd on it to see which shared libraries are required.

You could also recompile it from source to use static linking, and remove any external dependencies.

Or you could modify your script to use perl or something else that is already on the system to replace the sed functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I referred to [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) for your earlier question.
You can copy the `cygwin1.dll` along with [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) into a directory and it should work.

Here is another question discussing about [Setup of standalone cygwin applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485637/setup-standalone-cygwin-applications).
It suggests the use of [UnixUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) instead of Cygwin.